# Android Google Firebase Database Querying on Spinner

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

For example I have 4 children i the database:A, B, C, D. Each of them has an attribute named 'countryName'. Assume A has United Kingdom, B has France, C has Italy and D has Italy. These childer are displayed as a list and above the list is the spinner with 3 options - United Kingdom, France, Italy. By Default I see all 4 children in a list view. Lets say I choose United Kingdom on a Spinner and then I only see object A. Lets say I choose Italy on a Spinner and I see then objects C and D on a list View. I just do not know how to call the query to the database with various parameters. Here is my code for a spinner:

```
spinCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCountry);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.country_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinCountry.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

    spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Get whatever is chosen on a spinner
            String spinnerCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //Here is my query which on SQL would be 'SELECT * FROM THE DATABASE WHERE countryName EQUALS TO'country on a chosen on spinner'
            Query querySpinner = mLocationDatabaseReference.orderByChild("countryName").equalTo(spinnerCountry);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

[FIX]

So I managed to fix my problem by adding a listener as suggested by  Frank van Puffelen.

```
  mLocationAdapter.clear();

                querySpinner.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        locationCurrent = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationCurrent.class);
                        mLocationAdapter.add(locationCurrent);
                    }...
//Everything else is empty on addChildEventListener method so no point pasting it here
```

Comment: Your query seems fine. What are you asking? How to actually get the data from that query?

Comment: You'll need to [attach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) to get the query results. For many questions dealing with queries, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+query. They contain a lot of code that you can use for inspiration.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your LocationCurrent class?

Comment: I just got my problem fixed! Thank you guys. I thought I had to go a different way but there was much simpler solution. Please see my updated post to see how I fixed it

Comment: Please add your answer as a solution below, not as an update at the bottom of the question so that others my find it easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix my problem by adding a listener as suggested by Frank van Puffelen. The code below is inside `onItemSelected`method

```
mLocationAdapter.clear();

            querySpinner.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    locationCurrent = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationCurrent.class);
                    mLocationAdapter.add(locationCurrent);
                }...
//Everything else is empty on addChildEventListener method so no point pasting it here
```